# Setting angular 2 with VS2015

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, angular

I have a pretty annoying problem and I am not getting the right thing to do. Whenever I try to 'Restore Packages' by right clicking the file 'package.json' in Visual Studio 2015 I get:

> npm command completed with exit code 1

and nothing gets installed in my project.

I have a screen shot of the error I get you may see that:

[image]

Comment: Which version of `npm` you are using?

Comment: I am using 3.10.3 @abdulbarik

Comment: Can you check a node.js entry  in your `External Web Tools` tab  with a path of your node.js location?

Comment: Yes it is added as C:\Program Files (x86)\node.js

Comment: Put it on top and restart VS and restore package

Comment: It works! Thanks @abdulbarik

Comment: I am going to write this as an answer so that if anybody stuck with same they can easily find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid such type of issue you can do following things

> 1- Goto Tools>Options
>
> 2- Click 'Projects & Solutions' Tab and go to 'External Web Tools'.
>
> 3- Add a new entry of your local node.js installation  eg `c:/programms/nodejs/`(if not exist)  and move it to the top of the list.
>
> 4- Restart Visual Studio and restore packages.

That will work if `npm` version is at least `3.x.x`.

Comment: c:/programms/nodejs/ The programms folder not exist in C drive. still we required to add as new entry ?

Comment: Are you using windows and if yes then where you have installed Node.js?

Comment: Yes, using win8.1 OS, Nodesj installed under c:\Program Files (x86)\ folder

Comment: Did you try to load node.js from there?

Comment: I have set as per my node js installation path, but when I tried above  
c:/programms/nodejs/  it was not working thats why I confirmed it.